# JMeter: results via CSV about summary and graph without listeners

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

It's best practice to run JMeter tests without GUI without any enabled listeners.

Due to a report, I have to prepare after my test runs using the table from the summary listener and the graph from the graph listener, I usually let these listeners active in my test plan. The results from the summary and graph are saved as CSV files.

Q: How can I disable/remove those listeners and get summary tables and graph graphics CSVs anyway?

In my case, it's not useful to just use one results .jtl via the `-l results.jtl` switch when starting my .jmx. I don't even know which listeners (if any) are saved there. My test plan consists of several threads and each thread needs one summary table and one graph by default.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can generate a [JMeter HTML Dashboard Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from the .jtl results file like

   ```
   jmeter -g results.jtl -o /where/you/want/dashboard/to/be/generated
   ```
2. You can use [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) in order to produce any report or graph type out of the .jtl results file. You can install JMeterPluginsCMS using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager]

Comment: When I try your first option then I get `Error: Incompatible options --n/--nongui and -g/--reportonly found.` So it seems this is not doable in non-gui mode?

Comment: The above instruction is applicable for generating report from **existing** .jtl results file, if you want to generate dashboard along with test execution the syntax would be `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o /where/you/want/dashboard/to/be/generated`. Also be aware that you can upload your results file to [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/)  service to get it analyzed and see tables, charts, trends, etc. Moreover this way you will be able to compare results of several test runs.

Comment: Still not working: `./jmeter -n -t Scenarios.jmx -l results.jtl -e -o /html-Dashboards` gives `An error occurred: Cannot write to '/html-Dashboards' as folder does not exist and parent folder is not writable`. Folder exists and should be writeable. `./jmeter -n -t Scenarios.jmx -l results.jtl -e -o html-Dashboards` gives error `Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Results file:results.jtl is not empty`. After deleting the old jtl file my tests complete, but there is no file in my special folder and no other output file found.

Comment: Try removing the slash before `html-Dashboards` like `./jmeter -n -t Scenarios.jmx -l results.jtl -e -o html-Dashboards`. It looks you are running your test on Linux or MacOSX under non-privileged user and the folder `/html-Dashboards` does not exist

Comment: In my case it doesn't work with or without slash. Currently this is tried with macOS Sierra, yes. The folder is named `html-Dashboards` and chmod 777. Thanks for your help, Dmitri!